# Log4j FileAppender not working on jboss7

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x

I'm trying to use log4j to log information into a file. My log4j, which is located at src/main/resources/SIXSFD, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">

  <appender name="SYNC-PERFORMANCE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/Users/dcalderon/Desktop/log/sixsfd-bof" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout">
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.somepackage.PerformanceLoggerInterceptor" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SYNC-PERFORMANCE" />
  </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to log all information from *com.somepackage.PerformanceLoggerInterceptor* class into */Users/dcalderon/Desktop/log/sixsfd-bof*. This is what the class looks like:

```
package com.somepackage.interceptor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PerformanceLoggerInterceptor implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PerformanceLoggerInterceptor.class);
    private static final String SIMPLE_FORMAT = "{}|{}|{}|{}";

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logPerformance(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Object returnValue = invocationContext.proceed();
      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      logger.error(SIMPLE_FORMAT);
      return returnValue;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the file is being created but line *SIMPLE_FORMAT* is not being written on the file. Nevertheless, it is being logged on jboss server.log

Is there something wrong with my configuration?.

NOTE:
For some reason, I get this on jboss when deploying (jboss7):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I don't know how important that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JBoss AS 7 you need to [exclude log4j](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) and include your own version. You'll also want to ensure it ends up in your `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` directory so it ends up on the class path.

Comment: Yep, I was missing that jboss-deployment-structure file.